# Quarkus Kotlin Inject failure

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, quarkus

The @Inject annotation for a service, defined by "@ApplicationScope" fails to inject in Kotlin.

"kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property greeter has not been initialized"

The explanation on similar question:
"This problem results as a combination of how Kotlin handles annotations and the lack of the a @Target on the ... annotation definition. Add @field: xxx"

**Question is, how do I make this work for a service injection?**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.inject.Inject


class HelloRequest() {
    var firstName: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
}

@ApplicationScoped
open class HelloGreeter() {
    open fun greet(firstName: String?, lastName: String?): String {
        return "$firstName, $lastName"
    }
}

class HelloLambda : RequestHandler<HelloRequest, String> {

    @Inject
    lateinit var greeter: HelloGreeter

    override fun handleRequest(request: HelloRequest, context: Context): String {
        return greeter.greet(request.firstName, request.lastName)
    }
}
```

Similar questions:
"This problem results as a combination of how Kotlin handles annotations and the lack of the a @Target on the ... annotation definition. Add @field: xxx"

[Error to inject some dependency with kotlin + quarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458873/error-to-inject-some-dependency-with-kotlin-quarkus)

[SmallRye Reactive Messaging's Emitter<>.send doesn't send in Kotlin via AMQP broker with Quarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960858/smallrye-reactive-messagings-emitter-send-doesnt-send-in-kotlin-via-amqp-bro)

Comment: This happened to me when I had defined a ContainerRequestFilter in one project (a security specific project) and tried to use this as a dependency in another project (which contained my resource). The answer by OP fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the modified, @field: xx with a standard rest service, and by qualifying it with @field: ApplicationScoped, it does now work.

**The answer to my question above would be then that there is no runtime CDI when using the Quarkus Amazon Lambda extension.**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType


@ApplicationScoped
open class GreetingService2 {

    fun greeting(name: String): String {
        return "hello $name"
    }

}

@Path("/")
class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    @field: ApplicationScoped
    lateinit var service: GreetingService2

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    fun greeting(@PathParam("name") name: String): String {
        return service.greeting(name)
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun hello(): String {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: The `@field: …` modifier solved my problems. Thanks for posting this.